# I'm developing an app(android kotlin) that i need to show the sound amplitude in the UI

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to show the sound amplitude in the UI
but the value in the screen doesn't show the real time Decibel, it is too much delayed, and sometimes it shows -Infinity in the field.
Do i need to create a new handler/runnable?
And why is showing the -Infinity?

```
private fun startRecording(){

    if(!permissionGranted){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_CODE)
    return
}

    recorder = MediaRecorder()


    dirPath = "${externalCacheDir?.absolutePath}/"


    var simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.DD_hh.mm.ss")
    var date = simpleDateFormat.format(Date())
  
    filename = "audio_record$date"
    recorder.apply{


        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
        setOutputFile("$dirPath$filename.mp3")

        try{
            prepare()
        }catch(e: IOException){}

        start()

    }

    binding.btnRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause)
    isRecording = true
    isPaused =  false


    timer.start()


}


override fun onTimeTick(duration: String) {

    binding.tvTimer.text = duration //used to show the time of recording
    binding.waveView.addAmplitude(recorder.maxAmplitude.toFloat()) //used to draw waves of sound
    binding.tvMaxDecibel.text = ((20 * log10(recorder.maxAmplitude / 2700.0)).toFloat()).
    toString() // my problem is here, low refresh rate and shows the -Infinity
    

}
```

Comment: How often do you call `onTimeTick`?